# link Text wrapping spacing

Tags: html, css

I have a very long text string that wraps around fine, however, the text looks squeezed.
Is there a way to add some space between the wrapped text using css or anything else?
[image: Link I want to fix]

Comment: tried using `line-height`?

Comment: What does your HTML and CSS look like?

Comment: Thanks guys. I had to use line-height as suggested. Again, thank you.

Comment: You had some setting that was not disclosed in the question and actually caused the problem.

Comment: There was no setting or anything like that. There was only this css: h1 { color: blue; } And the width of the div was set to 600px so since the text was long it wrapped around, and I wanted to provide some space. Again all the comments were very useful, thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a CSS line height on the parent element:

`line-height:140%`;